SwiftUI app View not filling the entire iPhone screen
Adding iPhone (iOS SDK) as Supported Destination to a SwiftUI app in Xcode initially created for macOS, the content of the app view will not extend to the whole screen as it usually happens when you create a SwiftUI app with iPhone (iOS) as destination from the beginning.
The unmodified sample code of a SwiftUI app with the basic ContentView will look like this:

Steps to reproduce:

Create a macOS SwiftUI app
Add iPhone as a destination of the app target
Switch the Run Destionation to an iPhone and run the app

Expected result:
The content of the view should extend to the screen's bounds.

This can be fixed in two ways:

Adding Launch Screen key (UILaunchScreen) to your project's Info.plist. Thew value can also be just an empty dictionary.
Enabling Launch Screen (Generation) under Build Settings, that will add the UILaunchScreen key in the Info.plist file while during the build process. The corresponding key in the build settings is INFOPLIST_KEY_UILaunchScreen_Generation.

If you now run the app on an iPhone it should look the following.

